# React Native pass data with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to pass data to another screen on button click. I was using router-flux and it was working just fine, but on react-navigation it won't work.
So, on router-flux, on button click, it calls this function:

```
  onSearch() {
    fetch(`URL`, {
        method: 'GET',
        })
      .then((response) => { return response.json() } )
      .then((responseJson) => {
        Action.results({data: responseJson});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert("0 Cars!");
      });
  }
```

But on react-navigation, if I change the code to this:

```
  onSearch() {
    fetch(`URL`, {
        method: 'GET',
        })
      .then((response) => { return response.json() } )
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Resultados', { data: responseJson });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert("0 Cars!");
      });
  }
```

it won't work, I always get the alert "0 Cars!".
What am I doing wrong? On router-flux it was pretty straightforward.

This is how I call onSearch function:

```
    <Button onPress={this.onSearch} style={{backgroundColor: '#f48529', width: 140, borderRadius: 30, height: 40}} >
        <Text style={{color: 'white', fontFamily: 'rubik-light', fontSize: 17}}>Search</Text>
        <Icon size={15} name={'search'} color={'white'} />
    </Button>
```

Comment: You're doing the right thing, but your ajax request errors out if you pass inside the catch.

Comment: what do you mean? With router-flux, I only get "0 Cars!" if there is no data, but on react-navigation, even with data I get that alert and won't open the next screen. @WilomGfx

Comment: Why not try console.log(error) instead of alert 0 cars. So you know whats the error.

Comment: On the console I get this error: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined @cjmling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `onPress={this.onSearch}`  to `onPress={this.onSearch.bind(this)}`

And also

Try

```
onSearch() {

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    fetch(`URL`, {
        method: 'GET',
        })
      .then((response) => { return response.json() } )
      .then((responseJson) => {
        navigate('Resultados', { data: responseJson });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert("0 Cars!");
      });
  }
```

Comment: I get this error: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

Comment: @waze Had you edited your code as above in my answer? 1st.  const { navigate } line  .. 2nd. navigate(  line in then statement ?  And that error is on which line ?

Comment: Yes, I did.. But I also tried without those changes and the error is the same.

Comment: @waze Can you update your question how you are you calling onSearch ?

Comment: @waze i updated my answer above . try binding this onSearch

Comment: it opens the new screen now, but not showing any data. Do I have to access it differently than router-flux? On router-flux it was passed as props.

Comment: Sorry i never used router-flux may be try looking into documentations how to use it properly. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/